# JPanel not updating

Tags: java, arrays, swing, graphics, jpanel

I have a really odd problem where the JPanel I am making does not update every time. This is the method I use to update a JPanel which contains the map of my game. Calling on MapView creates a JPanel with the map inside it. However, sometimes the map refreshes with all the tiles in it displaying properly, and sometimes it only shows the tile in the top right.

```
public void updateMap(char[][] map){
    remove(mapView);
    revalidate();
            repaint();
    mapView = new MapView(logic, oCreator, 240, 240, map);
    mapView.setBounds(40, 80, 240, 240);
    add(mapView);
}
```

And the method inside the MapPanel class that draws the map:

```
public JPanel addMapPanel(char[][] map){
    int mapLength = map.length;
    int mapHeight = map[0].length;
    int tileSize = Math.min((length / mapLength), (height / mapHeight));
    absoluteMapHeight = tileSize * mapHeight;
    absoluteMapLength = tileSize * mapLength;
    JPanel mapFrame = new JPanel(new GridLayout(mapHeight, mapLength));
    mapFrame.setBackground(oCreator.getColorMedium());
    int counter = 0;
    for(int yIndex = 0; yIndex < mapHeight; yIndex++){
        for(int xIndex = 0; xIndex < mapLength; xIndex++){
            char charAtPos = map[xIndex][yIndex];
            JPanel tile;
                            //A tile is just a JPanel with the correct background.
            switch(charAtPos){
            //TODO Colours are placeholders.
            case '.':
                tile = createMapTile(Color.DARK_GRAY, tileSize);
                break;
            case '#':
                tile = createMapTile(Color.black, tileSize);
                break;
            case 'G':
                tile = createMapTile(Color.yellow, tileSize);
                break;
            case 'P':
                tile = createMapTile(Color.MAGENTA, tileSize);
                break;
            case 'E':
                tile = createMapTile(Color.RED, tileSize);
                break;
            default:
                tile = createMapTile(Color.blue, tileSize);
            }
            mapFrame.add(tile);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
    return mapFrame;
}
```

Sometimes it draws this: http://puu.sh/7Xcxo.png

And sometimes it draws the whole map: http://puu.sh/7XcAm.png

I am not sure why.

Comment: Try `repaint()` or `revalidate()` on the JPanels or even the JFrame.

Comment: Using setBounds suggests you are trying to do with out a layout manager, this precludes methods like invalidate, validate and revalidate, as these are related to updating the layout managers, try using an appropriate layout manager

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact that I am loading about 300 JFrames per pane?